# Store & Fetch data using session in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-4

Thank you in advance! I have one problem with the session. When I store and retrieve data, it works. I have a table, plan where I have 2 entries. 1st premium & 2nd freemium. It is just a subscripton process. So my question is when I click on the premium it should fetch the only premium but in my case, it prints premium & freemium. My code is as follows:

```
//Controller

1. getplan()

public function getPlan(){

        $plans = ComposerPlan::get();
        Session::put('plan', $plans);

        $this->layout->content = View::make('auth.authcomposer.composer-plan', compact('plans'));
    }

2. getComSignup

public function getComSignup(){

        // Show the page
        $value = Session::get('plan');
        $this->layout->content = View::make('auth.authcomposer.composer-signup', compact('value'));
    }

//Blade

//for put session
<a class="btn btn-default btn-green no-pjax plan-box @if($blanket) hidden @endif" data-plan-id="{{ $plan->id }}" href="{{ URL('/composer-signup')}}">Select Plan</a>

//for fetch session

@foreach($value as $v)
 {{$v->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I think,
You need to change your query, because you get both of subscriptions premium and freemium.

Maybe you need to add something like this, depend on your database.

```
$plans = ComposerPlan::where('subscription_type','premium')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $plans = ComposerPlan::get();
> Session::put('plan', $plans);
> ```

Makes no sense.

You are just putting all the records from your `ComposerPlan` table in your session

Solution depends on what is in your `ComposerPlan` table.

**If `ComposerPlan`has available plans and their data:**

You should have another table for relationship "user_id" + "plan_id". This relationship can also be stored in users table by just adding "plan_id" to it as user shouldn't have more than 1 plan as I understand

**If `ComposerPlan` is that relationship table:**

```
$plans = ComposerPlan::where("user_id", auth()->id())->first(); 
//note: first() will get 1 result so no foreach() should be used
```